# how to test collections of ActiveRecords in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I like RSpec, and I really like its `=~` array operator matcher to verify that an array contains a specific set of elements, regardless of ordering.

But not surprisingly, it tests pointer equality, not content equality, so the following won't work:

```
class Flea < ActiveRecord::Base ; end
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fleas
end

@d = Dog.create
@d.fleas << (@f1 = Flea.create)
@d.fleas << (@f2 = Flea.create)

@d.fleas.should =~ [@f1, @f2]
```

So I find myself frequently writing this in my RSpec tests:

```
@d.fleas.map {|f| f.id}.should =~ [@f1.id, @f2.id]
```

... which reeks of [bad code smell](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html).  Does RSpec provide a better way to verify a collection of ActiveRecord objects, regardless of the order returned?  Or at least is there a prettier way to code such a test?

Comment: Not putting this as an answer as I believe it smells also, but you could do `@d.flea_ids` rather than mapping.

Comment: True, but at your approach is more of a whiff than a reek... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Relations don't work like Arrays (as you found out). See [Issue #398 on the GitHub RSpec-Rails Issue board](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/398).

The answer is to add this line of code to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec::Matchers::OperatorMatcher.register(ActiveRecord::Relation, '=~', RSpec::Matchers::MatchArray)
```

Comment: Oh that is *so* cheating! By that I mean I wish I had thought of it first :) Nice work.

Comment: Lovely.  And it works.  Thanks!  (From the RSpec link, apparently you can also do `[*@d.fleas].should =~ [@f1, @f2]`, but registering the matcher feels like the better approach.)

Comment: Note that this is now standard - you don't need to register your own matcher for `=~` to work with `ActiveRecord::Relations`.